# Existence of minimum for a nonlinear functionnal

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, optimization, calculus-of-variations

How would you show that the functional $F$ defined as

$$F : u \mapsto \int_{(-1,1)} \big(u^{\prime \prime}(x)+u^{3}(x)\mathbb{1}_{u^{\prime}\neq0}(x) \big)^2dx$$

with $\mathbb{1}_{X}$ the indicator function of $X$, over the set

$$Y=\left\{u \in H^{2}((-1,1)),\quad \int_{\Omega}u(x)dx=0 \right\}$$

has a minimum?

The first thing I can say is that, since $F \geq 0$ then $\mu:=\inf_{u\in Y}F(u)$ exists and we have a sequence $(u_{n})_{n}\in Y^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}F(u_{n})=\mu$. To conclude I would like to have some compactness properties and lsc, which I think I don't have.

So, my question is, does anybody know of any other method with which to approach this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Why isn’t $u=0$ the minimum?

Comment: Does the sequence $u_n(x) = c_n x$ where $|c_n|\to 0$ count? We then have $F_n = 2c_n^7/7\to0$.

Comment: Good find @whpowell96 ,  this for certain shows that if a minimum exists it must be zero.

Comment: @Deane I would assume he wants to exclude the trivial case.

Comment: @K.defaoite, perhaps they should clarify.

Comment: @Deane Or perhaps the purpose of the exercise is to show that $u=0$ is the **unique** minimum.

Comment: Solutions to $u'' = -u^3$ are periodic and centered about zero, so you can probably find infinitely many initial conditions that yield that mean-zero condition. You can ignore the characteristic function in that case since the roots of $u'$ are countable. As the frequency of the oscillations increases, both $u$ and its derivatives increase so that sequence would be unbounded in $H^2$.

Comment: @K.defaoite, you’re guessing. It’s up to LLH to say more precisely what their question is.